# What does LTR kernel mean?

Tags: linux, kernel, version

I was reading some sites and came across (LTR) by the number of kernel. Can somebody explain what is means?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean LTS?

Comment: No, LTS is for distribution

Comment: No, LTS is a kernel thing (that distributions, on occasion, use). It means Long-Term Support.

Comment: So does that mean that RedHat does not change its kernel for 10 years, if the distro is supported for 10 years?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

LTR stands for Long Term Release.  This is also known as a LTSR, short for [Long Term Support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) Release.  These releases are supported for a longer time, and are meant to be used in Production Environments, where stability is preferred over new features.  In terms of the kernel you are reading about, the LTR cycle is about 3 years.  This means if you are a user who needs stability, if you download an LTR kernel, it will be supported upstream for the next 3 Years.  The definitive source for Linux Kernels are the [Linux Kernel Archives](https://www.kernel.org/).

Answer (score 4):

These are Long Term Releases:

> There are usually several "longterm maintenance" kernel releases provided for the purposes of backporting bugfixes for older kernel trees. Only important bugfixes are applied to such kernels and they don't usually see very frequent releases, especially for older trees.

Source: https://www.kernel.org/releases.html